# Lost transparency of the Default panel and a few questions about KDE

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, kde

sorry for possible language mistakes -- English is not my native language.
I've got two questions:

1. After I installed updates in my kubuntu 14.04 suddenly the Default panel lost its transparency. Why could that happen and how to fix it? This is not very critical to me, but it makes me ask another question, which has been bothering me for two months:
2. I've heard that KDE 4, which is used in my version of kubuntu will be no longer developing and will be changed on KDE 5. It sounds plausibly assuming I've found incredible amount of bugs in 4 version which are not being fixed for a long time. I use Ubuntu for work and need a stable and secure system, what am I supposed to do to keep it save? Does that mean, that I should use kubuntu 16.04 with its kde 5?

P.S. By the way, I find flat modern design disgusting, especially in kde 5, unfortunately.

Added:
Hmmm, greeting in the beginning of the post is cutted by some reasons... :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using kubuntu 16.04, had to install from scratch as i bought a new ssd drive, 16.04 for me has been very stable, looks good, feels stable, no crashes, despite running QT Creator, Firefox with hundreds of tabs, text editor, zim, krusader. ktorrent, virtual machines, kmail, telegram in 8GB ram. I highly recommend kubuntu 16.04 as very stable & highly configurable, whatever you don't like change it.